# Curl matrix operation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-analysis

Consider a vector field $\underline{{f}}:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.

We know that $\underline{\nabla}\cdot\underline{f} = tr(D\underline{f})$,

$D\underline{f} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
      \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial z} \\
      \frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial z} \\
      \frac{\partial f_{3}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_{3}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial f_{3}}{\partial z} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

and $tr : M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\ tr(A) = \sum_{i=1}^3a_{i,i}$

Can $\underline{\nabla}\times\underline{f}$ be defined as a matrix operation on the matrix $D\underline{f}$?

I know that $\underline{a}\times\underline{b} = $
$\begin{vmatrix}
\hat{\mathbf{i}} & \hat{\mathbf{j}} & \hat{\mathbf{k}} \\
a_x&a_y&a_z \\
b_x&b_y&b_z
\end{vmatrix}$

Can a function be defined $T:M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that

$T(D\underline{f}) = \underline{\nabla}\times \underline{f}$ explicitly?

Comment: $\nabla\times f$ is the vector $\left(\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial z},\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}\right).$ Since $Df$ contains all the partial derivatives occurring in that expression, the function $T$ from the question can certainly be defined. However, as far as I can see, this function $T$ doesn't have a "nice" expression in "well known" matrix functions like trace and determinant.

Comment: "We know that $\underline{\nabla}\cdot\underline{f} = tr(D\underline{f})$" This is only true in cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $Df - (Df)^T$ produces an antisymmetric matrix with the correct components--this is similar to how cross products can be computed by turning one of the vectors into an antisymmetric matrix and performing a matrix multiply.

This is a general result---any matrix $T$ can be decomposed as follows:

$$T = \frac{\alpha}{n} I + T_- + S$$

where $\alpha$ is the trace, $T_- = (T-T^T)/2$ is the antisymmetric part, and $S$ is a symmetric, tracefree matrix.  The trace corresponds to divergence, and the antisymmetric part corresponds to curl in 3d.  In fact, this definition can be used to define a "curl-like" operation in higher dimensions, for while cross products do not generalize, the antisymmetric part of $Df$ does.

Comment: That is a good insight about Df-(Df)^T having the correct components, but it's not clear to me how one would go from that matrix to the curl vector