What operation on matrices corresponds to the curl of a vector field?
Given the total derivative $Df$ of a (sufficiently) smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, the trace of the total derivative matrix corresponds to the divergence of $f$ (considered as a vector field $\mathbf{F}$), i.e. $\operatorname{trace}(Df) = \nabla \bullet \mathbf{F}$. (For context, I've asked a question about this result for the divergence on this website before.)

Question: Given a sufficiently smooth function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, what operation on matrices applied to its total derivative $Df$ corresponds to the (generalized) curl $\nabla \times f$?
In other words, what matrix operation is to "curl" as "trace" is to "divergence"?

Clarification: By "curl" I mean the general version, which is a "bivector field", I don't mean the vector field notion specific to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n=3$. However an answer that addresses at least that special case could still be accepted (provided it is a very strong hint for how to address the general $n$ case).
Also an answer addressing the "2D curl" from Green's theorem could also still be accepted (with the same caveat).
I was thinking that maybe something related to the minors of the total derivative considered as a matrix might be relevant, but I wasn't able to make that work. It also seems like the exterior derivative should be related to the antisymmetrization of the total derivative in some way (cf. this other previous question I've asked about that).
This other question is definitely related, but the given answer does not address this question: it neither gives a specific function of matrices for the curl, nor proves that no such function can exist. (It also seemingly ignores the case when $n\not=3$ and the fact that the curl still exists as a bivector field then.)

The operation on matrices that corresponds to the curl of the vector field $F$ is to take the antisymmetric part of the Jacobian $J=DF,:$ $$J-J^\top$$

The curl (and cross product) is a slightly awkward operation. A more natural product can be found in geometric algebra (the geometric product, which forms bivectors and blades). Note that per the way you have defined terms in your OP, you need to find a “matrix operator” that takes a matrix to a vector. But the curl is only defined in three dimensions, and so there won’t be a dimension-free type of general “matrix operation” that takes a matrix to a vector which is identical to the curl.

Just want to emphasize that @KurtG.'s answer is the correct one.

This question is similar to a previous one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186571/curl-matrix-operation although that one is explicitly about the 3d curl as a vector field.

$
\newcommand\dd{\mathrm D}
\newcommand\Tr{\mathop{\mathrm{Tr}}}
$Let $V$ be our (real) $n$-dimensional vector space. Something that must be noted is that divergence—being the trace of the differential—is an intrinsic quantity, but curl is not in the following sense: given any nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form $(v, w) \mapsto v\cdot w$ (henceforth, a metric), we can define a basis-independent symbol $\nabla$ in such a way that $v\cdot\nabla$ is the $v$-directional derivative and $\nabla\cdot f(x)$ is always the one and only divergence. The curl $\nabla\wedge f(x)$, however, is always dependent on the choice of metric. (Since you mention curl as being a bivector field, I am taking this expression as the definition of curl.)
Taking it on faith for the moment that $v\cdot\nabla f(x) = \dd f_x(v)$, what we want to do is extract a linear map $V \to V$ from the curl somehow. As a tensor, the curl acts on $V^{*}\wedge V^*$ in the following way
$$
  \langle\nabla\wedge f(x),\, \omega\wedge\eta\rangle = \omega(\nabla)\eta(f(x)) - \eta(\nabla)\omega(f(x)).
$$
Using the raising operator $\sharp : V^{*} \to V$, we can write this as
$$
  (\omega^\sharp\cdot\nabla)\eta(f(x)) - (\eta^\sharp\cdot\nabla)\omega(f(x)) = \eta(\dd f_x(\omega^\sharp)) - \omega(\dd f_x(\eta^\sharp)).
$$
In index notation, this reads
$$
  \eta_i\partial_jf^ig^{jk}\omega_k - \omega_k\partial_jf^kg^{ji}\eta_i = (\partial_jf^ig^{jk} - \partial_jf^kg^{ji})\omega_k\eta_i.
\tag{$*$}
$$
Here we see the metric ($g$) dependence very explicitly. To get a matrix, we want to raise one of $\omega$ or $\eta$; choosing $\eta$, we write
$$
  (\partial_jf^ig^{jk} - \partial_jf^kg^{ji})g_{il}\omega_k\eta^l = (\partial_jf^ig^{jk}g_{il} - \partial_jf^k\delta^j_l)\omega_k\eta^l = (g^{jk}\partial_jf^ig_{il} - \partial_lf^k)\omega_k\eta^l.
$$
The first term is exactly the metric adjoint $\overline{\dd f_x}$ of the differential, defined for any $T : V \to V$ by
$$
  v\cdot T(w) = \overline T(v)\cdot w
$$
for all $v, w \in V$. When $V = \mathbb R^n$ and the metric is the standard inner product, the adjoint is precisely the transpose of $T$ when expressed in the standard basis.
So we have that the following map $V \to V$ is equivalent to the curl of $f$ at $x$:
$$
  \overline{\dd f_x} - \dd f_x.
$$
In this sense the curl is the "antisymmetric part" of $\dd f_x$.

Returning to the index notation expression, let's forcibly raise $\omega$ as well:
$$
  (g^{jk}\partial_jf^ig_{il} - \partial_lf^k)\omega_k\eta^l = (g^{jk}\partial_jf^ig_{il} - \partial_lf^k)g_{km}\omega^m\eta^l = (\delta^j_m\partial_jf^ig_{il} - \partial_lf^kg_{km})\omega^m\eta^l
= (\partial_mf^ig_{il} - \partial_lf^kg_{km})\omega^m\eta^l.
$$
But now we can absorb the metric into $f$! We get
$$
  (\partial_mf_l - \partial_lf_m)\omega^m\eta^l.
$$
This is a new operation which takes in a (not necessarily linear) function $f : V \to V^{*}$—in other words, a one-form—and outputs a two-form. We can realize the parenthized expression as
$$
  (\dd f_x)^{*} - \dd f_x
$$
where by $({-})^{*}$ we mean the dual of a linear transformation; because $\dd f_x : V \to V^{*}$ it's dual is also $V \to V^{*}$ and the above expression makes sense. This is the exterior derivative.

What exactly is $\nabla$, and how can we see the metric (in)dependence of the curl (divergence)? How can we see more clearly the relationship between the curl and the exterior derivative?
Let $L : V^*\times V \to W$ be linear in the first argument. We define a symbol $\Delta$ which is analogous to $\nabla$ but covector like instead of vector like; we will write its argument on the left instead of the right so that $(v)\Delta$ is a scalar-like differential operator defined by
$$
  (v)\Delta f(x) = \dd f_x(v)
$$
for all $v \in V$.
We want to define $L(\Delta; x)$ with $\Delta$ differentiating the $x$-dependence. To this end, let $v \in V$ and $\omega\in V^*$. We consider the following manipulations reasonable:
$$
  L(\omega\,(v)\Delta; x) = (v)\Delta L(\omega; x) = \dd[L(\omega; {-})]_x(v).
$$
Contracting $\omega$ and $v$, which we write as $\Tr_{\omega(v)}$, we define
$$
  L(\Delta; x) = \Tr_{\omega(v)}\dd[L(\omega; {-})]_x(v).
$$
Call this the derivative of $L$. We already know of two derivatives:

Let $f : V \to V$ be any function, and define $L(\omega; x) = \omega(f(x))$. Then its derivative is the divergence of $f$, which we write as $(f(\dot x))\dot\Delta$. We use overdots to make it clear that $\Delta$ is differentiating $x$.
Let $\Psi$ be a differential form, i.e. a function $V \to \mathop\bigwedge V^*$, and let $L(\omega; x) = \omega\wedge\Psi(x)$. Then the derivative is the exterior derivative, which we write as $\Delta\wedge\Psi(x)$.

Let's write out the last one.
$$
  \Delta\wedge\Psi(x) = \Tr_{\omega(v)}\dd[\omega\wedge\Psi
]_x(v) = \Tr_{\omega(v)}\omega\wedge\dd\Psi_x(v).
$$
Now using index notation with a basis $e_i$ with dual $e^i$,
$$
  \Delta\wedge\Psi(x) = e^i\wedge\partial_i\Psi,
$$
which is the exterior derivative.
Now, given a metric we have the musical isomorphism $\sharp : V^* \cong V$, and we simply define
$$
  \nabla = \Delta^\sharp.
$$
Now it's clear why the divergence of $f : V \to V$ is metric-invariant:
$$
  \nabla\cdot f(x) = \Delta^\sharp\cdot f(x) = (f(\dot x))\dot\Delta.
$$
In a sense, the metricity of $\nabla$ and the metricity of $\cdot$ "cancel out". We also see why the curl is metric dependent
$$
  \nabla\wedge f(x) = \Delta^\sharp\wedge f(x)
$$
and the relationship with the exterior derivative is readily apparent.
Finally, we easily derive that
$$
  v\cdot\nabla f(x) = v\cdot\Delta^\sharp f(x) = (v)\Delta f(x) = \dd f_x(v).
$$

This is a very comprehensive answer, thank you! Is there any reference you would recommend that goes through some of this material more slowly? "Here we see the metric () dependence very explicitly. To get a matrix..." <-- that part is not saying that the Jacobian is metric dependent, correct? Or is it saying that? Is $\nabla$ not the same as the Jacobian here, given that $v \cdot \nabla f(x) = D_x f (v)$? Or am I oversimplifying things? (Because seemingly by the same heuristic $\Delta$ would also be the Jacobian, but $\nabla$ and $\Delta$ have different "type signatures".)

This answer also appears to address the extent to which the exterior derivative is something similar to an "antisymmetrization" of the Jacobian, so you could consider posting (part of) it as the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4849220/does-the-hessian-correspond-to-the-exterior-derivative-of-the-gradient-1-form-o  and I would accept that answer too, if you want.

Here is another question that appears to be relevant to this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908008/why-isnt-there-a-contravariant-derivative-or-why-are-all-derivatives-covarian specifically the way the answer defines multiple kinds of "derivative" of varying "covariance" / "contravariance" (signature).

@hasManyStupidQuestions I don't have a reference for this specific take; in particular, the explicit definition of $L(\Delta)$ for any $L$ and $\Delta\wedge f$ being the exterior derivative is not something I've seen done elsewhere. (I should also note this is all taking place in flat space; manifolds are more complicated.)

@hasManyStupidQuestions The Jacobian (i.e. total differential) is not metric dependent; in the same way that the divergence is independent of metric so is $v\cdot\nabla=(v)\Delta$. The symbol $\nabla$ is not the Jacobian, the map $v\mapsto v\cdot\nabla f$ is the Jacobian of $f$. The symbol $\nabla$, as I have defined it, is what you get when you take the covector-like $\Delta$ and make it vector-like by using the metric. Put another way, you can use $\Delta$ to differentiate any contravariant tensor without a metric, but you need a metric to define $\nabla$ and differentiate covariant tensors.

The metric dependence in the curl is in forming the adjoint $\overline{\mathrm Df_x}$.

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\n{\nabla}
\def\BR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\curl#1{\op{curl}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1{\op{grad}\LR{#1}}
\def\skew#1{\op{skew}\LR{#1}}
\def\cross#1{\op{\large\Psi}\LR{#1}}
\def\q{\quad}
\def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q}
\def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\w{\wedge}
\def\t{\times}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\deriv#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}
$In $\R3$ the $\sf Cross\ Product\ Matrix\ (CPM)$ of a vector $b$ is defined as
$$\eqalign{
\cross b \doteq \m{
 \;0&-b_3&\;\;b_2 \\
 \;\;b_3&\;0&-b_1 \\
 -b_2&\;b_1&\;0 \\
}
}$$
Now consider the $\sf CPM$ of the cross product of two vectors
$$\eqalign{
\cross{b\t a} &= \LR{ab^T-ba^T} \;\doteq\, -2\,\skew{ba^T} \\
}$$
Substituting the $b$ vector with the $\n$ operator yields
$$\eqalign{
\cross{\n\t a}
  &= -2\,\skew{\n a^T} 
  &= -2\,\skew{\grad a} \\
}$$
In higher dimensions neither the cross product nor the curl exist, but the gradient does.
And the skew part of the gradient is the nearest analog of the curl operation.

Dumb question, but is this supposed to say "skew part of the Jacobian" or "skew part of the gradient"?

(For convenience purposes I'll express it all in $\mathbf R^3$)
I couldn't get to the usual expression.
$$\nabla\times \mathbf F=\left(\partial_yF_z-\partial_zF_y\right)\mathbf{\hat x}+\left(\partial_zF_x-\partial_xF_z\right)\mathbf{\hat y}+\left(\partial_x F_y-\partial_y F_x\right)\mathbf{\hat z},$$
but your jacobian or total derivative is related to the curl like this
$$\text Df-\text D^\top f=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -(\nabla\times \mathbf F)_z & (\nabla\times \mathbf F)_y\\
(\nabla\times \mathbf F)_z & 0 & (\nabla\times \mathbf F)_x\\
-(\nabla\times \mathbf F)_y & -(\nabla\times \mathbf F)_x & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Maybe multiplying by some specific matrix or vector you'll get the full expression (I couldn't find one though).
